# how to rotate a 3D vector around arbitrary axis

Tags: graphics3d, vector

I have three vectors red, blue, and green and their origins are at `(x,y,z)` where red and blue are perpendicular and can be rotated together in the x-y plane by tunning angle \phi. This part is done, now I would like to add a green vector  (must always be perpendicular to red) that can be rotated by angle \theta around the red vector. my code is working fine only with `(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)` but with,e.g., `(1,1,0)` green vector does not rotate around the red one properly. How can I fix this, please?

steps to generate this are:

- I start with a vector `aA` where its origin located at arbitrary point `(x,y,z)` (the blue one)
- then to get a perpendicular vector to the blue one I just rotated `aA` by angle `\pi/2` and get the red vector.
- last step is to create a vector that can be rotated around the red one and perpendicular to it (green one).

here is the code

```
aA = {-2, 0, 0};

rot4[x_, y_, z_, \[Phi]x_, \[Theta]z_] := {Black, 
  Sphere[{x, y, z}, 0.1], Blue, 
  Arrow[RotationTransform[\[Phi]x, {0, 0, 1}, {x, y, 
      z}][{{({x, y, z}), ({x, y, z} + aA)}}]], Red, 
  Arrow[{{x, y, z}, 
    RotationTransform[\[Pi]/2, {0, 0, 1}, {x, y, z}][
     RotationTransform[\[Phi]x, {0, 0, 1}, {x, y, z}][
      aA + {x, y, z}]]}], Green, 
  Arrow[RotationTransform[\[Theta]z, 
     RotationTransform[\[Pi]/2, {0, 0, 1}, {x, y, z}][
      RotationTransform[\[Phi]x, {0, 0, 1}, {x, y, z}][
       aA + {x, y, z}]], {x, y, z}][
    RotationTransform[\[Phi]x, {0, 0, 1}, {x, y, 
       z}][{{({x, y, z}), ({x, y, z} + aA)}}]]]}

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{rot4[0, 0, 0, \[Phi]x, \[Theta]z]}, Boxed -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 300, FaceGrids -> {Left, Back, Bottom}, 
  FaceGridsStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5], 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}], {\[Phi]x, 0, 
  2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}, {\[Theta]z, 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you state more clearly how the green vector is not doing what you want? It seems to be rotating in the plane for which red would be a normal vector, which is how I would interpret what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected and somewhat simplified version:

```
rot4[x_, y_, z_, ϕx_, θz_] := 
  Module[{orig = {x, y, z}, red0 = 4 {1, 0, 0}, blue0 = 4 {0, 1, 0}, 
    green0 = 4 {0, 0, 1}}, {red, blue} = 
    RotationTransform[ϕx, {0, 0, 1}] /@ {red0, blue0};
   green = RotationTransform[θz, red][green0];
   {Black, Sphere[orig, 0.1], Red, Arrow[{orig, orig + red}], Blue, 
    Arrow[{orig, orig + blue}], Green, Arrow[{orig, orig + green}]}];

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{rot4[-1, -1, 0, ϕx, θz]}, ImageSize -> 300, 
  FaceGrids -> {Left, Back, Bottom}, FaceGridsStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5],
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}], {ϕx, 0, 
  2 π, π/20}, {θz, 0, 2 π, π/20}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but still not working unless (x,y,z)=(0,0,0) as you posted and even you need to change the rotation of the green vector to be around red not red-aA to get it correct and this just working fine in my code. the problem arises when (x,y,z)=(1,1,0) this problem persists in your code too and even the angle between red and blue is not \pi\2 anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I should work now.

Comment: Awesome, I see how it should be done.  doing everything at the origin (0,0,0) and then move it to the desired one. Thanks!